# Delete multiple variable columns mentioned in worksheet in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete multiple columns of a newly created workbook stated in the original workbook.
The columns to be deleted are mentioned in one column and the number of column-sequences may be variable.
So far I tried to go through it with a loop which does not work currently. Furthermore, it's not a good practice, since after deletion the rows shift which makes it hard to name the correct columns up for deletion.

Currently, i am receiving an error in the For-next-loop. The Columns-Statement doesn't seem to work.

For your information: I am fairly new to VBA and programming. If you have any more tips or hints reading my code, please give me a sign, I am very happy to improve my VBA-skills.

```
Sub CleanPlan()

' Define columns up for deletion as variable array
' Use .Transpose to ensure one-dimensional array
    Dim DelCol As Variant
    DelCol = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export").Range("B4:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row))

' Open origin file, save as .xlsx
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export").Range("B1").Value
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\name22.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\name22.xlsx"

' Delete columns from array
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To UBound(DelCol)
        Columns("""" & DelCol(i) & """").Delete
    Next i
' more code, irrelevant at this point
```

There must be a better practice to solve this issue. I am very thankful for any tips!

Comment: What is the error? On which line?

Comment: When deleting rows or columns, step backwards so you dont accidentally miss some... `For i = UBound(DelCol) To 1 Step -1`

Comment: @Teamothy Forgot to mention, it's the For-Next-Loop. The Columns-Statement won't work.

Comment: @braX Such a simple thing. This already makes a big difference in how to name the columns up for deletion. Thanks!

Comment: I also recommend not to rely on `ActiveWorkbook` instead use a construct like `Set MyWb = orkbooks.Open(Filename:=…)` and then `MyWb.SaveAs(…)`. This is much more reliable! • Also in `Columns("""" & DelCol(i) & """").Delete` it is not defined in which workbook and worksheet the `Columns` is. Don't let Excel guess (it might fail).

Comment: And what is in `DelCol`? If letters those """" are ok, if numbers those """" are not necessary. To be more resistant to error, according to @braX - `For i = UBound(DelCol) To LBound(DelCol) Step -1`

Comment: @Teamothy DelCol is column-letters. For example DelCol(1) = R:F. So I need the """".

Comment: @lks Actually you don't need the `""""` at all. If you use a variable in `Columns()`. Try `var = "B:C": Columns(var).Select` and see that it works without the `""""`. And the same works if `var` is set to be the value of a cell like `var = Range("A1").Value` and A1 has `B:C` in it without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing you loop with this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Long
Dim holdInt As Long

' refactor array to numbers:
For i = 0 To UBound(sortArray)
    sortArray(i) = GetColumnNumber(Replace(Left(sortArray(i),2), ":", ""))
Next i

' sort array
For i = 0 To UBound(DelCol)
   For x = UBound(DelCol) To i + 1 Step -1
      If DelCol(x) < DelCol(i) Then
         holdInt = DelCol(x)
         DelCol(x) = DelCol(i)
         DelCol(i) = holdInt
      End If
   Next x
Next i

' delete column from right to left
For i=UBound(DelCol) to 0 step -1
    Columns(DelCol(i)).Delete
Next i
'-------------------------------------------------
Function GetColumnNumber(text As String) As Long
Dim r As range

Set r = range(Trim(text) & 1)

GetColumnNumber = r.Column

End Function
```

This will sort you array of columns' numbers, and then will go from end to start so the shift not affect column numbers.

**UPDATE**

Added a general idea of function to refactor array from Column letters to Column numbers before sort. You need to update to make some checks whether your column letters cover couple of rows (e.g. "A:B", instead of "A:A") or whether if you have columns further than "ZZ:ZZ".